# Javascript: Member-variable-accessing closures

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, member

I'm wondering how to deal with member variables in closures in JavaScript. The following code alerts "6".

```
function testy()
{
    function blah()
    {
        this.a = 5;
        this.func = function()
        {
            this.a = 6;
            alert(this.a);
        }
    }

    var x = new blah;
    x.func();
}
```

but this code alerts 5.

```
function testy()
{
    function execute(func)
    {
        func();
    }

    function blah()
    {
        this.a = 5;
        this.func = function()
        {
            execute(function()
            {
                this.a = 6;
            });

            alert(this.a);
        }
    }

    var x = new blah;
    x.func();
}
```

How do I pass a closure which still accesses the member variables of the enclosing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
execute(function()
{
   this.a = 6;
});

function execute(func)
{
    func();
}
```

Your calling the function as `func();` and by default without specifying a context `this` will resolve to the global context which is `window` in the browser.. There are three options you can use here.

**make `this` local**

```
var that = this;
execute(function()
{
   that.a = 6;
});
```

Now `that` points to the correct `this`.

**bind `this` scope to the function**

```
execute((function()
{
   this.a = 6;
}).bind(this));
```

This will bind the correct / expected `this` scope to your function. Note that [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is ES5 and will break older browsers. [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) is a reasonable cross browser alternative.

**edit execute**

```
function execute(f, context) {
    f.call(context);
}

execute(function() {
    this.a = 6;
}, this);
```

Your passing the context as an extra parameter to execute. Then execute will call [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to make sure that the function is called with the desired context

Comment: I wouldn't say "immediatly scopes to window." but that it *resolves* to the global object, which is equivalent to `window` in browsers. There is enough confusion about `this` in javascript without infering it has something to do with scope. :-)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! But is there a typo ("that" instead of "this") in your "bind" example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function blah()
{
    this.a = 5;
    this.func = function()
    {
        var self = this;
        execute(function()
        {
            self.a = 6;
        });
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
```